# Skew planar wheel antenna - is it circularly polarised or not?

Tags: antenna, electromagnetism, radio, radiation, ham-radio

'Skew planar wheel' antennas are popular for uhf. They are often described as circularly polarised, but I don't see how they would be. Are they instead just a mixed polarisation omnidirectional antenna ?

[image]

If they are circularly polarised, where would the equivalent 90 degree phase shift come from, as used in a normal circularly polarised antenna.

This account of testing this antenna indicated strong circular polarisation:

> The results showed that this Skew-Planar is strongly right-hand circularly polarized, as expected.  At my end, Clare's signal was S8 with his right-hand helix, and dropped to S1 when he switched to his left-hand helix.

http://www.ve3byt.com/SkewPlanarAntenna/

Practical designs discussed here, also noteworthy is that the polarization is apparently determined by the direction of lean(skew?) of the four elements : http://www.slvrc.org/902band/skewplanar.htm

Comment: Hi and welcome! Please can you paste in a picture or diagram of one of these antennas, to get us started?

Comment: Updated with an image

Comment: Hmm.  If we only had two "blades" instead of four, and if each one emits in a dipole pattern (like any loop antenna,) then we actually have two vertical dipole antennas with a 1/2lambda separation, with a 90deg twist.   In a horizontal line through the two, we'd expect pure circ-polarized emission.  Cool!  Two "propellors" with opposite screw, they can't hear each other!

Comment: @wbeaty I don't follow. Where is the 90 degree phase difference coming from between the elements?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Figure 10 of this excellent explanation](http://www.antenna-theory.com/antennas/cloverleaf.php) boils down to this:

If you ignore all the currents that cancel each other out due to symmetry, you can  physically guide (via the copper) three currents Ez of similar magnitude and phase in the z-direction and one equivalent current in the y-direction, the resulting two **equal and orthogonal currents being spaced a quarter wavelength** apart.

So, with currents of equal magnitude and phase, orthogonal **and** spaced a quarter wavelength apart - voila, circular polarization!

[image: Planar Wheel Antenna Primary Currents]

Comment: Interesting, I've added a link to http://www.slvrc.org/902band/skewplanar.htm with practical designs. While I follow both of the ways you describe, I can't reconcile that with what I see on that site - apparently symmetrical designs - there doesn't appear to be a transmission line different, and with consistent element lengths? Also noteworthy is that the polarization direction appear to be determined by the lean or 'skew' of the elements themselves, this I still do not understand!

Comment: Agreed. I watched your reference & then dug further for a good explanation that considers the perfect symmetry, then edited my response. Pretty cool once you see Figure 10!

Comment: Thanks, I think that explanation is as good as it's going to get, although it is still challenging to 'visualize' coherently. 

The explanation highlights a need for symmetry, what is interesting is that 3 and 5 lobe designs are being sold. Also some that are not curved but with straight lobes. It's hard to see how these would work well or be beneficial. A good gallery is at http://www.maxmyrange.com/assumptions.html